# "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" error

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I am getting this erron using retrofit post api.

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 48 path $.data
```

My pojo class is given below:

```
public class InFo_Post {

private String status;
private String msg;
private DataModel data;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public DataModel getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(DataModel data) {
    this.data = data;
}

private class DataModel {

    private String skill_years;
    private String skill_where;
    private String about_work;
    private String skill_images;

    public String getSkill_years() {

        return skill_years;
    }

    public void setSkill_years(String skill_years) {

        this.skill_years = skill_years;
    }

    public String getSkill_where() {

        return skill_where;
    }

    public void setSkill_where(String skill_where) {

        this.skill_where = skill_where;
    }

    public String getAbout_work() {

        return about_work;
    }

    public void setAbout_work(String about_work) {

        this.about_work = about_work;
    }

    public String getSkill_images() {

        return skill_images;
    }

    public void setSkill_images(String skill_images) {

        this.skill_images = skill_images;
    }
}

}
```

The response is given below:

```
 {
"status": "Success",
"msg": "Skill saved successfully. With 0 image. Failed to upload 1 image.",
"data": {
    "skill_id": "3",
    "user_id": "30",
    "skill_years": "12",
    "skill_where": "hjujjhj",
    "about_work": "dvsvsdvds",
    "skill_images": ""
  }
  }

Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 48 path $.data
```

Why is this error issued?

Comment: please provide the code when you send the data using Retrofit

Comment: jsonObject = new JsonObject();,jsonObject.addProperty("skill_images", String.valueOf(myImageList));
        RetrofitInterface jsonpost = ServiceGenerator.createService(RetrofitInterface.class,"http://littletreasure.org.in/");
        Call<InfoPost> call = jsonpost.post(jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<InfoPost>() {

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: jsonObject.addProperty("skill_images", String.valueOf(myImageList)); 
As it clear, myImageList is a list and when you convert it to string, it's still an array.

Comment: actually this is just demo code but actually i am getting a multiple of image in bitmap in array then i will send it through the retrofit, so please help me i din't get any successful response, how can i deal with it, please help me, i am struggling from 2-3 days and i am still getting failed message......what should i do?

Comment: anyone can please help me guy's.

Comment: skill images when empty it's a string, replace it with [] instead

Comment: how can i do that please tell me